# How to find any date format in a string

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I need to get all dates in any formats from an string.

for example:

```
string text = "aaaaa25/01/2019 21:22:56 dfgdfv cvcvbcvb 25/02/18 2:12 asdfd";
```

I need a methods that extract all the dates

> 25/01/2019 21:22:56,
>   25/02/18 2:12

as DateTime.

I try by Regex:

```
var splitter = new Regex("[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}");
foreach (Match m in splitter.Matches(str))
{
    string dateString = m.Groups[0].Value;
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss", null);
}
```

But I need to write any formats and there is a lot options.
I looking for method that detect any format of datetime.

Comment: Hello dor, have you tried anything to solve your problem? People love to see your effort first. On the other hand, how do you think to solve ambiguous formats like `01/02/2019`? Do you have all format patterns that your string _may_ include? Without these information, it is imposible to answer your question. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times.

Comment: _But I need to write any formats and there is a lot options_ **Exactly**. Before you parse your `string` to `DateTime`, you _have to_ know what kind of format(s) your string contains. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to write a code that handles all formats. Also regular expressions aren't usually suitable for this kind of parsing tasks in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```regex
/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/(?:\d{2}){1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{2}(:?:\d{2})?/gm
```

For a few pieces:

`\d{1,2}` matches 1 or two digits.

`(?:\d{2}){1,2}` matches a group of two digits once or twice. (therefore, 2 or 4 digits)

`(?:\d{2}:)?` allows the seconds to be optional

Comment: Regular expressions are _usually_ an overkill on this kind of tasks. I wouldn't sugggest to use them for DateTime parsing. Your regex won't match for `11/11/2019` by the way. https://regex101.com/r/zkznLZ/1

Comment: If you want to make the time optional, use `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/(?:\d{2}){1,2}(?: \d{1,2}:\d{2}(:?:\d{2})?)?`.